# Вывод в datagridView

Tags: c#, база-данных, winforms

делаю вывод данных из бд в datagridview но после вывода у меня все данные есть но они не видны в datagridview только при клике в ячейки появляется текст. Вот весь код

```
    using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace NetDevice
{
    public partial class DevForm : Form
    {
        private SqlConnection db = null;
        private SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        private SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
        private DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        public DevForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void DevForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            db = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Netdb"].ConnectionString);
            show();
        }

        private void Res_dev_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.txtId.Text = "";
            this.txtName.Text = "";
            this.txtManuf.Text = "";
            this.txtAmount.Text = "";
        }
        private void Ins_dev_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (this.txtName.Text == "")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please Enter a Name...");
            }
            if (this.txtManuf.Text == "")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please Enter a Manufacter...");
            }
            if (this.txtAmount.Text == "")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please Enter a Amount...");
            }
            else
            {
                string Name = txtName.Text;
                string Manuf = txtManuf.Text;
                string Amount = txtAmount.Text;
                int amount = Int32.Parse(Amount);
                db.Open();
                string qry = "Insert into Devices (Name, Manufacter, Amount) values ('" + Name + "','" + Manuf + "','" + amount + "')";
                cmd = new SqlCommand(qry, db);
                if (cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() == 1)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Device insert with Name: " + Name);
                }
                else
                    MessageBox.Show("Device inserted  failed with Name: " + Name);
                db.Close();
                Res_dev_Click(sender, e);
            }
        }
        void show()
        {
            adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Devices", db);
            dt = new DataTable();
            adapter.Fill(dt);
            Grid_Devices.Rows.Clear();
            foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            {
                int n = Grid_Devices.Rows.Add();
                Grid_Devices.Rows[n].Cells[0].Value = dr[0].ToString();
                Grid_Devices.Rows[n].Cells[1].Value = dr[1].ToString();
                Grid_Devices.Rows[n].Cells[2].Value = dr[2].ToString();
                Grid_Devices.Rows[n].Cells[3].Value = dr[3].ToString();

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Вот фото как мне показывают все данные, хотя они должны быть видны изначально. Пожалуйста помогите, заранее спасибо
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: измените фон datagrid или измените цвет текста внутри ячеек. Цвет фона совпадает с цветом текста - скорее всего.

Comment: А как через свойство это изменить?

Comment: Не работайте со строками грида напрямую. Используйте привязку данных. `adapter.Fill(dt); Grid_Devices.DataSource = dt;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужны коллекции этих параметров:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

О GridColor я думаю вам не стоит говорить.